# Enabling debug on Wildfly domain mode in Docker - port already in use

Tags: debugging, networking, docker, port, wildfly

I'm providing full docker environments for a team of developers, comprising Wildfly, MySQL and Apache primarily.
I preconfigure all images according to production and a developer has now requested one more option: to be able to use intellij to debug a running wildfly slave.

The setup:
I set up a virtual machine to host docker as people use different OS'.
I forward ports that must be reachable from the local machine that hosts the VM. This works, they can access the DB, wildfly management etc. Screenshot of the VM configuration and ports here:
[debian machine hosting docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G7r8.png)

Dockerfile for host with debugging on (which isnt working):

```html
FROM ourerpo/wildfly:base

ARG VERSION=8.2.0

WORKDIR $JBOSS_USER_HOME

ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8787,server=y,suspend=n'

ADD srv srv/

RUN mkdir -p $JBOSS_CONF \
    && mv srv/wildfly.conf.slave $JBOSS_CONF/wildfly.conf \
    && chown $JBOSS_USER:$JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_CONF \
    && chmod 644 $JBOSS_CONF \
    && chown $JBOSS_USER:$JBOSS_USER srv/ -R \
    && chmod 744 srv/*.sh

USER $JBOSS_USER

# Move in template host configuration and insert slave key
RUN mv srv/host-slave-${VERSION}.tmpl $JBOSS_DOMAIN/configuration/host-slave.xml \
    && cat $JBOSS_DOMAIN/configuration/host-slave.xml | sed -e"s@<secret value=\".*\"/>@<secret value=\"somevalue\"/>@" >$JBOSS_DOMAIN/configuration/host-slave.xml.new \
    && mv $JBOSS_DOMAIN/configuration/host-slave.xml.new $JBOSS_DOMAIN/configuration/host-slave.xml

ENTRYPOINT exec /app/wildfly/bin/domain.sh --domain-config=domain.xml --host-config=host-slave.xml -Djboss.domain.master.address=stsdomain -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

The image when spawned as a container logs the following:

```html
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /app/wildfly

  JAVA: /app/java/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8787,server=y,suspend=n

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
14:58:27,755 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
14:58:27,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) JBAS012017: Starting process 'Host Controller'
[Host Controller] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[Host Controller] ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
[Host Controller] ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
[Host Controller] JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
[Host Controller] FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
14:58:28,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (reaper for Host Controller) JBAS012010: Process 'Host Controller' finished with an exit status of 134
```

Two things to note:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8787,server=y,suspend=n

ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
```

So the port should be in use, using netstat I can't see it though:

```html
me@machine:~/mapped$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8050                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::13080                :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::15672                :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9990                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5671                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 172.17.0.1:123          0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 172.10.12.1:123         0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 fe80::1053:e1ff:fed:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::2c88:1cff:fe9:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::42:3dff:fe28::123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::58c3:fdff:fe3:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::d435:6fff:fee:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::8091:1aff:fe7:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::2459:65ff:fe0:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::94b2:9fff:fe6:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::42:19ff:fe2f::123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 fe80::a00:27ff:fef4:123 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -
```

Docker inspect on container:

```html
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "9ac8dad9fd93a0fb9bdff4c068b8e925aa9ff941df4f81033ce910a093f36a78",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "11080/tcp": null,
                "8787/tcp": null,
                "8899/tcp": null
```

Things I have tried:
Changing `-Djava.awt.headless=t                                           rue -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8787`
To `-Djava.awt.headless=t                                           rue -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787`

Change port from 8787 to something else.
Exposed the port, not exposing the port. 
Server=y, Server=n

I'm running:
Docker version 1.11.2,
Wildfly 8.2
Docker network inspect:

```html
me@machine:~/mapped$ docker network inspect compose_stsdevnet
[
    {
        "Name": "compose_thenet",
        "Id": "9a17953da5f9698f3f27cf18d9d41751d049774439a53629fdcd69a996e370db",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.10.12.0/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
<other containers here>

<failing container>            "9094b4136707e643df69fdff7dc04432a8d9c36275c3ae6dc6f2286393d3753a": {
                "Name": "stupefied_stonebraker",
                "EndpointID": "0c425d16334ecf3127233156d9770dc286bf72f57d778efe01fafb4696a17012",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:0a:0c:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.10.12.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
<the domain>            "e4dd4f67f33df6643c691aa74a71dc4a8d69738004dfbe09b20c3061bd3bc614": {
                "Name": "stsdomain",
                "EndpointID": "0c89e70edbddb34f7be6b180a289480e1ac57ef482a651f0addce167eaa1110a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:0a:0c:18",
                "IPv4Address": "172.10.12.24/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By placing the value in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable it will be used for both the process controller and the host controller. You're seeing the error because the host controller already has a debug agent listening on port 8787 when the process controller tries to bind to it.

My guess would be you want to actually debug your application on the servers. If that is the case in your `host-slave.xml` you'd need to add something like the following to a specific server.

```xml
<jvm name="default">
    <jvm-options>
        <option value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"/>
    </jvm-options>
</jvm>
```

Example:

```xml
<servers>
    <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
        <jvm name="default">
            <jvm-options>
                <option value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"/>
            </jvm-options>
        </jvm>
    </server>
    <server name="server-two" group="other-server-group">
        <!--
          ~  server-two avoids port conflicts by incrementing the ports in
          ~                  the default socket-group declared in the server-group
          -->
        <socket-bindings port-offset="150"/>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Comment: It works! :)
Didn't think about it being used on both processes. Thanks for the quick answer and explanation.